# Why assertEquals and assertSame in junit return the same result for two instances same class?

Tags: java, junit, equals, assert

According to documentation

> assertEquals() Asserts that two objects are equal.
>
> assertSame() Asserts that two objects refer to the same object.

So I am expecting that if I have a class like below

```
class SomeClass {}
```

then

```
SomeClass someClass1= new SomeClass();
SomeClass someClass2= new SomeClass();
assertSame(someClass1,someClass2); // fail
assertEquals(someClass1,someClass2); // fail
```

the assertEquals should pass and assertSame should fail, as the value of both classes are equal but they have different reference location.

As I get failure in both cases then my question is what are the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Since you didn't override equals in your class, `assertEquals` behaves the same as `assertSame` since the default equals implementation compare references.

```
150    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
151        return (this == obj);
152    }
```

If you provide a dumb overriding of equals:

```
class SomeClass {
    @Override 
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

you'll see that `assertEquals` succeeds.

Answer (score 19):

`assertEquals` uses `equals()` method (that you should override in your class to really compare its instances) to compare objects, while `assertSame` uses `==` operator to compare them. So the difference is exactly the same as between `==` (compare by value) and `equals` (compare identity).

Answer (score 12):

**Official JUnit documentation:**

> assertEquals: Asserts that two objects are **equal**.
>
> assertSame: Asserts that two objects refer to the **same object**.

In other words

> assertEquals: uses the equals() method, or if no equals() method was overridden, compares the reference between the 2 objects.
>
> assertSame: compares the reference between the 2 objects.

**Example 1**: equals method was **not** overridden, so assertSame and assertEquals return the same result, since they compare the objects' reference.

```
public class A {    
    private int i;
    public A(int i){ this.i = i; }
}

public class TestA {
    final A a1 = new A(0);
    final A a2 = new A(0);

    @Test
    public void assertsame_testAssertSame(){
        assertSame(a1, a2); // AssertionError: expected:<test2.A@7f13d6e> but was:<test2.A@51cdd8a>
    }

    @Test
    public void assertsame_testAssertEquals(){
        assertEquals(a1, a2); // AssertionError: expected:<test2.A@7f13d6e> but was:<test2.A@51cdd8a>
    }
}
```

**Example 2**: equals method was overridden, so assertSame and assertEquals return the not same result, since the equals method will be used by assertEquals this time.

```
public class A {
    private int i;
    public A(int i){ this.i = i; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        // self check
        if(this == o){ return true; } else
        // null check
        if(o == null){ return false;} else
        // type check and cast
        if(getClass() != o.getClass()){ return false; } else {
            final A a = (A) o;
            // field comparison
            return Objects.equals(a, a);
        }
    }
}
public class TestA {
    final A a1 = new A(0);
    final A a2 = new A(0);

    @Test
    public void assertsame_testAssertSame(){
        assertSame(a1, a2); // AssertionError: expected:<test2.A@7f13d6e> but was:<test2.A@51cdd8a>
    }

    @Test
    public void assertsame_testAssertEquals(){
        assertEquals(a1, a2); // OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

assertEquals: **==**
assertSame:   **===**

'same' matches the type along with the value which is the same as '==='.

Comment: I don't understand why I got downvoted as this is an accurate description. Please leave your reasoning before downvoting...

Comment: I think the reason is you tried to explain from javascript perspective and someone not liked it and haven't understood it.

Comment: Pretty much any language! Not just JavaScript.

Comment: This is java question. Java does not have ===. JavaScript has.

Comment: There is no === in Java, C++, Python, and many other languages. This answer only makes sense to JavaScript programmers.

Comment: also makes sense for php

Answer (score 0):

The first assert fails because `someClass1` and `sameClass2` are not the same instances. The second assert fails because `equals(Object)` method hasn't been defined in `SomeClass` and its super `equals(Object)` does reference equality. Since two different instances are compared for equality, this one fails for the same reason as the first.

Answer (score 0):

**assertEquals** - It check the objects are equal or not based on the overridded equals() method of that class. So we can check the equality of object based on their state(compare the values of their instance variables).

assertEquals()
The assertEquals() method compares two objects for equality, using their equals() method.

```
@Test
public void assertEquals_example() {
    Employee employeeNew = new Employee();
    employee.setSalary(1000000.0);
    assertEquals("EMPLOYEE OBJECT", employee, employeeNew);
}
```

If the two objects are equal according to there implementation of their equals() method, the assertEquals() method will return normally. Otherwise, the assertEquals() method will throw an exception, and the test will stop there.

**assertSame() and assertNotSame()**
The assertSame() and assertNotSame() methods tests if two object references point to the same object or not. It is not enough that the two objects pointed to are equals according to their equals() methods. It must be exactly the same object pointed to.

Here is a simple example:

```
@Test
public void assertSame_assertNoSame_example() {

    assertSame(employeeService.getEmployeeFromId(1), employeeService.getEmployeeFromId(1));
    assertNotSame(employee, employeeService.getEmployeeFromId(1)); // We will get null as response
}
```