# Junit using assert method to compare two prepared statements

Tags: junit, prepared-statement

I'm testing two prepared statement as you will see below and I want it to show that they are the same using the assertEquals but its throwing me an error that the result and expectedResult are not equal.

```
public PreparedStatement setSQL(String sql) throws SQLException {

try {

pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

} catch (SQLException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

return pst;

}


public void testSetSQL() throws SQLException {

        String sql = "SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN member ON student.ssn=member.ssn WHERE ssn = ?";

        result = dbconn.setSQL(sql);

        // expsql = ;

        expectresult = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM student INNER JOIN member ON student.ssn=member.ssn WHERE ssn = ?");

        assertSame(expectresult, result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451925/why-assertequals-and-assertsame-in-junit-return-the-same-result-for-two-instance) and its answers to understand what `assertSame` means. It checks for equality of two object references and that is certainly not the case for your code since two distinct `connection.prepareStatement(...)` calls would give you two different references/objects.

I am not sure how does equality of `PreparedStatement` works, you can check its source code for `equals()` method (`PreparedStatement` is simply an interface in JDK, its implementation is provided by driver providers ) and see of `assertEquals` is what you need.

Your code is working as expected.

Quoting from [prepareStatement(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)),

> Returns:
>       a new default PreparedStatement object containing the pre-compiled SQL statement

Comment: Nowhere is `PreparedStatement` documented to have value equality semantics.